# Need to get the monthly reviews count from Google

Tags: google-people-api

I need to get the monthly reviews count and total count from Google reviews details.
I have checked the below documentation but could not found about it.
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details

Comment: Any update here..?

Comment: please check below link I hope this will help you. https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data

Comment: I have read documentation. But could find any filter things to get the reviews.

Comment: Using GMB api. The only options are pageSize, pageToken, and orderBy there is no date filter option available.                                                                        You can accomplish this using the GMB API also by parsing all the reviews and storing them in a temp array or DB, and looping through that array where review date is >= your start date variable and <= your end date variable;                                         also You can try a third-party API as well; https://www.reviewsmaker.com/api/date-range/